# Eiffel avoiding duplicates into ecf file

Tags: eiffel, eiffel-studio-19.12

I have duplicate classes into a used library. How can I specify on the ecf file that I want to exclude a path?

```
Error code: VD71

Configuration error


Duplicate class: BASIC
/home/pg/data/solarity/sit-dev/eiffel/lib/thirdparty/json/examples/performance/basic.e
/home/pg/data/solarity/sit-dev/eiffel/lib/thirdparty/json/examples/basic/basic.e
Configuration: /home/pg/data/solarity/sit-dev/eiffel/sit-platform/sit_platform_lib.ecf
```

one way I found can be

```
<library name="json" location=".\..\lib\thirdparty\json\library\json.ecf" readonly="false"/>
        <file_rule>
                <exclude>
                        /examples$                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                </exclude>
        </file_rule>
```

But can't find the definition of excluding paths and its syntax

Comment: Are you aware of your own question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/63607115/6607497) that seems to ask for the very same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism to control source code outside a library. The file rules to include and exclude source files are supported only for clusters.

You need to fix the library configuration to make sure is has no duplicate classes.

**Note.** Project settings dialog is a recommended way to change project settings, because it reflects only supported options, and ensures the configuration file does not get broken. In particular, it shows that clusters have exclusion rules in *Source code* section, whereas libraries do not.