# eiffel: cluster has two classes with the same name

Tags: eiffel, conflicting-libraries, eiffel-studio-19.12

How to deal with `cluster has two classes with the same name` with eiffel studio?

when I want to choose between 2 versions?
Where can I find documentation about that?

[image]

Think that there is a trick with `sources->renaming`
[image: io]

Answer (score 2):

Quite trivial in fact...

just click the `sources->renaming` item and you'd be able to rename classes like below
[image]

there are some more options I didn't try [into the documentation](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffelstudio/Group_Options)